# Trigger/Listen Some/On Provider On Message Web Socket Channel Flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket

I have been looking to distribute the socket connection to listen or trigger some/on provider.

My case i have some API that need to hit when signal from socket `onMessage` is coming. service is inside of provider and used more then one widget. so when the signal is comming then triggre the provider so the state will change on all of widget where provider was listed.

I have estabilish the socket connection on base widget, and have been connected. I have `websocket.dart` class and here is my websocket on message handler:

```
onMessage(dynamic data) {
    final Map decoded = jsonDecode(data);
    final body = decoded["body"];

    switch (body) {
      case "authenticated":
        Log.info("Wss conn is authenticated.");
        _connected = true;
        return;
      case "fetchNotification":
        Log.info("fetchNotification");
        return;
      case "authenticated":
        Log.warning("Wss conn is unauthenticated.");
        _connected = false;
        establishConnection();
        return;
      default:
        Log.warning("Invalid signal body");
    }
  }
```

from code above on `fetchNofication` signal need to trigger some provider to hit the API and updating some widget.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for now, I wrapped all the websocket classes to extend the provider. so all widgets that need to listen for ws signal must use websocket provider. but this is not good enough i think